# Install ceres for iOS

Tags: ios, cmake, ceres-solver

I'm trying to install ceres for iOS (both for devices and the simulator, but I think I understand the concept of making them twice and link them with lipo)

As the toolchain needs to be from the iOS SDK, the code should look like this:

```
cmake \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../ceres-solver/cmake/iOS.cmake \
-DEIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/eigen/header \
-DIOS_PLATFORM=<PLATFORM> \
<PATH_TO_CERES_SOURCE>
```

Where do I find the `/path/to/eigen/header`? is it just
`-DEIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.4 \`

I more or less understanding it to be:
`-DIOS_PLATFORM= OS \`  and then make it again for `-DIOS_PLATFORM= SIMULATOR64 \`

But what does `<PATH_TO_CERES_SOURCE>` mean? Is this where I want to have the file? Or should I follow the macOS install and refer to that path?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`<PATH_TO_CERES_SOURCE>` is basically just the folder you have downloaded and unzipped. So in your case it would just be 'ceres-solver'...